# How to clear all user data when user clicked on cancel button while add data in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

In `ng2-smart-table` when user add data and instead of add data clicked on cancel button and again clicked on add then it shows old field data.

I need to set that when user clicked on cancel button, His field data must be clear.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table)

I have searched a lot but I didn't find any help and I have also checked in it's doc and they are not providing it's event.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ng2-smart-table` doc, there is no any event for this. If you want then you might update it's `node-module` file.

Make sure after update that you will not get it changes when you make a build of the app.

Comment: Yes, You are correct but still I'm looking a way that how could I do changes in node-modules.